# Problema al cambiar campo que agregué a una tabla de MySql en un proyecto de Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, error500

les molesto con una consulta. Hace poco descargué un proyecto en Laravel para hacer unas pruebas, lo que quería hacer era agregar un campo nuevo a la bd e integrarlo al programa, pero me percaté que me daba un error al agregar el nuevo campo al modelo, el controlador y las vistas. Así que intenté simplemente modificar uno de los campos ya existentes y reemplazarlo por el que yo creé en la BD de Mysql, lo reemplacé tanto en el modelo, las vistas, y el controlador, pero ahora que intento hacer una transacción me da un error 500 (antes de la modificación el proyecto funcionaba perfectamente). Agradecería en gran manera cualquier ayuda, pues es para un proyecto, disculpen la molestia soy nuevo con Laravel.
A continuación agrego imágenes de los cambios que realicé, lo que hice fue cambiar el campo "cantidad" por "cantidad2" algo que consideré sencillo.

EL MODELO

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DetalleVenta extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'detalle_ventas';
    protected $fillable = [
        'idventa', 
        'idproducto',
        'cantidad',
        'precio',
        'descuento',
        'cantidad2'
    ];
    
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

EL CONTROLADOR

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Venta;
use App\DetalleVenta;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DB;


class VentaController extends Controller
{
    //
    
    public function index(Request $request){
      
        if($request){
 
            $sql=trim($request->get('buscarTexto'));
            $ventas=Venta::join('clientes','ventas.idcliente','=','clientes.id')
            ->join('users','ventas.idusuario','=','users.id')
            ->join('detalle_ventas','ventas.id','=','detalle_ventas.idventa')
             ->select('ventas.id','ventas.tipo_identificacion',
             'ventas.num_venta','ventas.fecha_venta','ventas.impuesto',
             'ventas.estado','ventas.total','clientes.nombre as cliente','users.nombre')
            ->where('ventas.num_venta','LIKE','%'.$sql.'%')
            ->orderBy('ventas.id','desc')
            ->groupBy('ventas.id','ventas.tipo_identificacion',
            'ventas.num_venta','ventas.fecha_venta','ventas.impuesto',
            'ventas.estado','ventas.total','clientes.nombre','users.nombre')
            ->paginate(8);
             
 
            return view('venta.index',["ventas"=>$ventas,"buscarTexto"=>$sql]);
            //return $ventas;
        }
      
 
     }
 
        public function create(){
 
             /*listar las clientes en ventana modal*/
             $clientes=DB::table('clientes')->get();
            
             /*listar los productos en ventana modal*/
             $productos=DB::table('productos as prod')
             ->join('detalle_compras','prod.id','=','detalle_compras.idproducto')
             ->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(prod.codigo," ",prod.nombre) AS producto'),'prod.id','prod.stock','prod.precio_venta')
             ->where('prod.condicion','=','1')
             ->where('prod.stock','>','0')
             ->groupBy('producto','prod.id','prod.stock','prod.precio_venta')
             ->get(); 
 
 
             return view('venta.create',["clientes"=>$clientes,"productos"=>$productos]);
  
        }
 
         public function store(Request $request){
         
         
             try{
 
                 DB::beginTransaction();
                 $mytime= Carbon::now('America/Guatemala');
 
                 $venta = new Venta();
                 $venta->idcliente = $request->id_cliente;
                 $venta->idusuario = \Auth::user()->id;
                 $venta->tipo_identificacion = $request->tipo_identificacion;
                 $venta->num_venta = $request->num_venta;
                 $venta->fecha_venta = $mytime->toDateString();
                 $venta->impuesto = "0.20";
                 $venta->total=$request->total_pagar;
                 $venta->estado = 'Registrado';
                 $venta->save();
 
                 $id_producto=$request->id_producto;
                 $cantidad2=$request->cantidad2;
                 $descuento=$request->descuento;
                 $precio=$request->precio_venta;
 
                 
                 //Recorro todos los elementos
                 $cont=0;
     
                  while($cont < count($id_producto)){
 
                     $detalle = new DetalleVenta();
                     /*enviamos valores a las propiedades del objeto detalle*/
                     /*al idcompra del objeto detalle le envio el id del objeto venta, que es el objeto que se ingresó en la tabla ventas de la bd*/
                     /*el id es del registro de la venta*/
                     $detalle->idventa = $venta->id;
                     $detalle->idproducto = $id_producto[$cont];
                     $detalle->cantidad2 = $cantidad2[$cont];
                     $detalle->precio = $precio[$cont];
                     $detalle->descuento = $descuento[$cont];           
                     $detalle->save();
                     $cont=$cont+1;
                 }
                     
                 DB::commit();
 
             } catch(Exception $e){
                 
                 DB::rollBack();
             }
 
             return Redirect::to('venta');
         }
 
         public function show($id){
 
             //dd($id);
             //dd($request->all());
            
             /*mostrar venta*/
 
             //$id = $request->id;
             $venta = Venta::join('clientes','ventas.idcliente','=','clientes.id')
             ->join('detalle_ventas','ventas.id','=','detalle_ventas.idventa')
             ->select('ventas.id','ventas.tipo_identificacion',
             'ventas.num_venta','ventas.fecha_venta','ventas.impuesto',
             'ventas.estado','clientes.nombre',
             DB::raw('sum(detalle_ventas.cantidad2*precio - detalle_ventas.cantidad2*precio*descuento/100) as total')
             )
             ->where('ventas.id','=',$id)
             ->orderBy('ventas.id', 'desc')
             ->groupBy('ventas.id','ventas.tipo_identificacion',
             'ventas.num_venta','ventas.fecha_venta','ventas.impuesto',
             'ventas.estado','clientes.nombre')
             ->first();
 
             /*mostrar detalles*/
             $detalles = DetalleVenta::join('productos','detalle_ventas.idproducto','=','productos.id')
             ->select('detalle_ventas.cantidad2','detalle_ventas.precio','detalle_ventas.descuento','productos.nombre as producto')
             ->where('detalle_ventas.idventa','=',$id)
             ->orderBy('detalle_ventas.id', 'desc')->get();
             
             return view('venta.show',['venta' => $venta,'detalles' =>$detalles]);
         }
         
         public function destroy(Request $request){
 
             $venta = Venta::findOrFail($request->id_venta);
             $venta->estado = 'Anulado';
             $venta->save();
             return Redirect::to('venta');
 
        }
 
         public function pdf(Request $request,$id){
         
             $venta = Venta::join('clientes','ventas.idcliente','=','clientes.id')
             ->join('users','ventas.idusuario','=','users.id')
             ->join('detalle_ventas','ventas.id','=','detalle_ventas.idventa')
             ->select('ventas.id','ventas.tipo_identificacion',
             'ventas.num_venta','ventas.created_at','ventas.impuesto',
             'ventas.estado',DB::raw('sum(detalle_ventas.cantidad2*precio - detalle_ventas.cantidad2*precio*descuento/100) as total'),'clientes.nombre','clientes.tipo_documento','clientes.num_documento',
             'clientes.direccion','clientes.email','clientes.telefono','users.usuario')
             ->where('ventas.id','=',$id)
             ->orderBy('ventas.id', 'desc')
             ->groupBy('ventas.id','ventas.tipo_identificacion',
             'ventas.num_venta','ventas.created_at','ventas.impuesto',
             'ventas.estado','clientes.nombre','clientes.tipo_documento','clientes.num_documento',
             'clientes.direccion','clientes.email','clientes.telefono','users.usuario')
             ->take(1)->get();
 
             $detalles = DetalleVenta::join('productos','detalle_ventas.idproducto','=','productos.id')
             ->select('detalle_ventas.cantidad2','detalle_ventas.precio','detalle_ventas.descuento',
             'productos.nombre as producto')
             ->where('detalle_ventas.idventa','=',$id)
             ->orderBy('detalle_ventas.id', 'desc')->get();
 
             $numventa=Venta::select('num_venta')->where('id',$id)->get();
             
             $pdf= \PDF::loadView('pdf.venta',['venta'=>$venta,'detalles'=>$detalles]);
             return $pdf->download('venta-'.$numventa[0]->num_venta.'.pdf');
         }
 
     
}
```

LA VISTA CREATE QUE ES LA QUE ME DA EL ERROR 500

```html
@extends('principal')
@section('contenido')


<main class="main">

 <div class="card-body">

 <h2>Agregar Compra</h2>

 <span><strong>(*) Campo obligatorio</strong></span><br/>

 <h3 class="text-center">LLenar el formulario</h3>

    <form action="{{route('compra.store')}}" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}

            <div class="form-group row">

            <div class="col-md-8">  

                <label class="form-control-label" for="nombre">Nombre del Proveedor</label>
                
                    <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="id_proveedor" id="id_proveedor" data-live-search="true">
                                                    
                    <option value="0" disabled>Seleccione</option>
                    
                    @foreach($proveedores as $prove)
                    
                    <option value="{{$prove->id}}">{{$prove->nombre}}</option>
                            
                    @endforeach

                    </select>
                
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">

                <div class="col-md-8">  

                        <label class="form-control-label" for="documento">Documento</label>
                        
                        <select class="form-control" name="tipo_identificacion" id="tipo_identificacion" required>
                                                        
                            <option value="0" disabled>Seleccione</option>
                            <option value="FACTURA">Factura</option>
                            <option value="TICKET">Ticket</option>
                            

                        </select>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group row">

                <div class="col-md-8">
                        <label class="form-control-label" for="num_compra">Número Compra</label>
                        
                        <input type="text" id="num_compra" name="num_compra" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el número compra" required pattern="[0-9]{0,15}">
                </div>
            </div>

            <br/><br/>

            <div class="form-group row border">

                 <div class="col-md-8">  

                        <label class="form-control-label" for="nombre">Producto</label>

                            <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="id_producto" id="id_producto" data-live-search="true">
                                                            
                            <option value="0" selected>Seleccione</option>
                            
                            @foreach($productos as $prod)
                            
                            <option value="{{$prod->id}}">{{$prod->producto}}</option>
                                    
                            @endforeach

                            </select>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">

                <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label class="form-control-label" for="cantidad">Cantidad Jalapa</label>
                        
                        <span><input type="number" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" class="form-control" value="0" onFocus="if (this.value=='0') this.value='';" pattern="[0-9]{0,15}"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="cantidad2">Cantidad Monjas</label>
                    
                    <span><input type="number" id="cantidad2" name="cantidad2" class="form-control" value="0"onFocus="if (this.value=='0') this.value='';" pattern="[0-9]{0,15}"></span>
            </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label class="form-control-label" for="precio_compra">Precio Compra</label>
                        
                        <input type="number" id="precio_compra" name="precio_compra" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese precio de compra" pattern="[0-9]{0,15}">
                </div>

               

                <div class="col-md-3">
                        
                    <button type="button" id="agregar" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i> Agregar detalle</button>
                </div>


            </div>

            <br/><br/>

           <div class="form-group row border">

              <h3>Lista de Compras a Proveedores</h3>

              <div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
                <table id="detalles" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="bg-success">
                        <th>Eliminar</th>
                        <th>Producto</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Cantidad Jalapa</th>
                        <th>Cantidad Monjas</th>
                        <th>SubTotal</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                 
                <tfoot>
                  

                    <tr>
                        <th  colspan="5"><p align="right">TOTAL:</p></th>
                        <th><p align="right"><span id="total">USD$ 0.00</span> </p></th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="5"><p align="right">TOTAL IMPUESTO (20%):</p></th>
                        <th><p align="right"><span id="total_impuesto">USD$ 0.00</span></p></th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th  colspan="5"><p align="right">TOTAL PAGAR:</p></th>
                        <th><p align="right"><span align="right" id="total_pagar_html">USD$ 0.00</span> <input type="hidden" name="total_pagar" id="total_pagar"></p></th>
                    </tr>  

                </tfoot>

                <tbody>
                </tbody>
                
                
                </table>
              </div>
            
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer form-group row" id="guardar">
            
            <div class="col-md">
               <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
              
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save fa-2x"></i> Registrar</button>
            
            </div>

            </div>

         </form>

    </div><!--fin del div card body-->
  </main>

@push('scripts')
 <script>
     
  $(document).ready(function(){
     
     $("#agregar").click(function(){

         agregar();
     });

  });

   var cont=0;
   total=0;
   sumcant=0;
   subtotal=[];
   $("#guardar").hide();

     function agregar(){

          id_producto= $("#id_producto").val();
          producto= $("#id_producto option:selected").text();
          cantidad= $("#cantidad").val();
          cantidad2= $("#cantidad2").val();
          precio_compra= $("#precio_compra").val();
          impuesto=20;
        
          
          if(id_producto !="" && cantidad!=""&& cantidad2!="" && precio_compra!=""){
            
             sumcant= parseFloat(cantidad)+parseFloat(cantidad2);
             subtotal[cont]=sumcant*precio_compra;
             total= total+subtotal[cont];
             
             var fila= '<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i></button></td> <td><input type="hidden" name="id_producto[]" value="'+id_producto+'">'+producto+'</td> <td><input type="number" id="precio_compra[]" name="precio_compra[]"  value="'+precio_compra+'"> </td>  <td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"> </td> <td><input type="number" name="cantidad2[]" value="'+cantidad2+'"> </td> <td>$'+subtotal[cont]+' </td></tr>';
             cont++;
             limpiar();
             totales();
            
             evaluar();
             $('#detalles').append(fila);
            
            }else{

               // alert("Rellene todos los campos del detalle de la compra, revise los datos del producto");
               
                Swal.fire({
                type: 'error',
                //title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'Rellene todos los campos del detalle de la compras',
              
                })
            
            }
         
     }

    
     function limpiar(){
        
        $("#cantidad").val("");
        $("#cantidad2").val("");
        $("#precio_compra").val("");
        

     }

     function totales(){

        $("#total").html("USD$ " + total.toFixed(2));

        total_impuesto=total*impuesto/100;
        total_pagar=total+total_impuesto;
        $("#total_impuesto").html("USD$ " + total_impuesto.toFixed(2));
        $("#total_pagar_html").html("USD$ " + total_pagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#total_pagar").val(total_pagar.toFixed(2));
        
     }



     function evaluar(){

         if(total>0){

           $("#guardar").show();

         } else{
              
           $("#guardar").hide();
         }
     }

     function eliminar(index){

        total=total-subtotal[index];
        total_impuesto= total*20/100;
        total_pagar_html = total + total_impuesto;
       
        $("#total").html("USD$" + total);
        $("#total_impuesto").html("USD$" + total_impuesto);
        $("#total_pagar_html").html("USD$" + total_pagar_html);
        $("#total_pagar").val(total_pagar_html.toFixed(2));
       
        $("#fila" + index).remove();
        evaluar();
     }

 </script>
@endpush

@endsection
```

IMAGEN DE LA TABLA EN LA BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL ERROR FINAL
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Un error 500 indica un problema con el código de lado del servidor, edita y agrega el texto del log de errores de Laravel

Comment: Normalmente un error 500 indica que hay un problema con el servidor, no necesariamente debe ser problema de la BD. Ahpra, has intentado revisar los logs que te genera tu servidor (Ya sea que uses Xampp o Laragon). Checa los logs y escribe que errores te aparecen, así puedes dar un contexto mas amplio. porque ahorita se encuentra confuso.

Comment: coloca el .env con el debugger true y asi podremos ver cual es el error